# Jquery callback function in post cannot execute

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to retrieve data from mysql. I just wanna do a simple test.

The js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("http://anonymous.comze.com/default.php",
    function(data){
      alert(data);
    });
});
});
<?
    echo 'hello';
?>
```

Why the callback function doesn't work?

Comment: Is this code also running on `http://anonymous.comze.com`?  Do you see any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your site is running on anonymous.comze.com, your issue is with the browser enforcing the Same Origin Policy.  Specifically, you can't make an AJAX call (which .post() is doing) to a domain other than the one that served your page.  There are a number of workarounds to this issue, including using the $.ajax function with JSONP, or not using an AJAX request.  Some ideas here:

[Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

If you're just testing, though, probably the easiest way to get it working is to use Chrome and disable the security settings (of course, restart your browser without this flag before doing any real browsing - also note that this flag is marked as unsupported, so it may vanish from future versions of Chrome).  You have to start it from the command line using something like (this is for the OSX terminal):

```
open Google\ Chrome.app --args --disable-web-security
```

For the PC, you should be able to just open a command window and navigate to your Chrome directory under program files and then use:

```
chrome.exe --args --disable-web-security
```

You will get a warning once the Chrome window opens, but the Same Origin Policy will be disabled for the duration that the browser window is open.